# Rotation over a list in pygame

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, rotational-matrices

If I can get some help I will post more of this code. It is a bit weird. I picked it up from a video and cleaned it up a bit. Basically it captures all the *x*  coordinates in `cam.pos[0]`, all the *y* coordinates in `cam.pos[1]`, and all the *z* coordinates in `cam.pos[2]`.
My 3D environment has a few dozen cubes of which I can go towards, away, above, below, to the left and to the right. But I cannot turn.
This is my attempt at a corkscrew:

```
while True:
 dt = clock.tick()/1000
 rot = clock.tick()/1000
 r = rot*36
 for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_x:
             cam.pos[0] = cam.pos[0]*np.cos(r)-cam.pos[1]*np.sin(r)
             cam.pos[1] = cam.pos[0]*np.sin(r)-cam.pos[1]*np.cos(r)
             cam.pos[2] = cam.pos[2]
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

     cam.events(event)
 screen.fill((0,0,0))
 face_list = []; face_color = []; depth = []
 for obj in cubes:

     vert_list = []; screen_coords = []
     for x,y,z in obj.verts:
         x-=cam.pos[0]; y-=cam.pos[1]; z-=cam.pos[2]
```

I can post more if anyone is interested. It does not return any errors but neither is it corkscrewing.
Thanks.

Dropping in the code is not working out for some reason. 
You can look at it here: [python_flyer](https://github.com/DangerousTod/TanksALot/blob/master/flyer.py)

You can see I have made changes:

```
datax = cam.pos[0]
datay = cam.pos[1]
for i in range(datax):
for j in range(datay):
cam.pos[0] = i * np.cos(r) - j * np.sin(r)
cam.pos[1] = i * np.sin(r) - j * np.cos(r)
```

The error is now:

```
for i in range(datax):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I call that progress

Comment: If I understand correctly you want an object to move in a corkscrew-like motion, so in a circle in the XY plane and forward in the Z axis. Correct?
If so then your motion would be `x(t)=R*cos(w*t), y(t)=R*sin(w*t), z(t)=v*t` where `w` is the angular speed for the circular motion and `v` is the linear speed in the Z direction.

Comment: buzjwa Mathematically correct, however in the key up, key down nature of trying to rotate dozens of vertices it is not quite working as it should. I am not worried about moving in the z direction at this point as I can already move in the z direction. So if you look at the snip I posted you will see that this is exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, after the line

> ```
> cam.pos[0] = cam.pos[0]*np.cos(r)-cam.pos[1]*np.sin(r)
> ```

the value in `cam.pos[0]` is changed. So the result of

> ```
> cam.pos[1] = cam.pos[0]*np.sin(r)-cam.pos[1]*np.cos(r)
> ```

depends on the calculation of the former expression.

Store the content of `cam.pos` to local variables, before the rotation is computed.
Further the formula for the rotation is wrong. See [Rotation matrix - In two dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions):

> ```
> x` = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta)
> y` = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta)
> ```

e.g.

```
x, y, z = cam.pos    
cam.pos[0] = x * np.cos(r) - y * np.sin(r)
cam.pos[1] = x * np.sin(r) + y * np.cos(r)
cam.pos[2] = z
```

---

Don't call [`clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) twice in a row. This function returns the number of milliseconds which have passed since the previous call. So the 2nd call will always return 0.0.

Your camera position is (0, 0, -5). If this position is rotated around the z axis by any angel, then the result is still (0, 0, -5). Rotate it around the y axis.

Try the following code, which will animate your scene:

```py
while True:
    ticks = clock.tick()
    dt = ticks/1000
    rot = ticks/1000

    r = rot
    x, y, z = cam.pos    
    cam.pos[0] = x * np.cos(r) - z * np.sin(r)
    cam.pos[1] = y 
    cam.pos[2] = x * np.sin(r) + z * np.cos(r)
```

Comment: Rabbid76 This is worth a shot, I am not sure that cam.pos[0] will provide x,y,z but you do see the problem. I have been thinking I might try threading.

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: for i in range(datax) gave me floats, so I think that is the way to go because the position of the camera never changes. Cam.pos[0] - [2] are columns of coordinates. I will try your suggestions though I think I may have already tried those things. Did you follow the link?

Comment: I appreciate your insight. I certainly was calling clock a second time. But your code does not work.

Comment: @JonathanEngwall Of course I've tested my code, but I can't know the context, in which you use the code.